# Selenium cssSelector works in IDE but not in Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a web system I am automating using `Java/Selenium Webdriver`.  I have an item I am trying to get access to.  It has a compound class name.  I have tried all the solutions I have been able to find here and so far none of them work.

The most offered solution looks like this:

```
By elem = By.cssSelector("div.prdbox.saleshdr");
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(elem);
System.out.println("Number of Items found: "+elements.size());
```

When I check the size of the elements array it is always zero.

What I am finding however is that when I put the selector string in to the `Selenium IDE (2.9.1)` and use the "Find" button it identifies the correct web element without any problem at all.

I am at a loss for why it works in the `IDE` but not in my code.

Comment: make sure that the element is present before you invoke `findElements()`.  you can do this by using [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).

Comment: Well color me embarrassed.  I forgot to check that.  That's it exactly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the element using its XPath? In the past when I ran into issues trying to select something using cssSelector, I often had success when I tried its XPath instead.

Answer (score 0):

Give some wait time before the selector you are taking.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.prdbox.saleshdr"));
System.out.println("Number of Items found: "+elements.size());
```

or try to find the elements with the help of Xpath or id.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));
```

Hope it will help you